# When mapping FindMinimum to a list, how to find out which instance does not converge

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I defined a function `f[x,y]` and wanted to study its minimum over `x` when viewing `y` as a parameter. So I did the minimization for a list of values of `y`

```
yList = Table[i/100.0, {i, 1, 99}];
res = FindMinimum[f[x, #], x] & /@ yList;
```

The problem is that the minimization does not converge for some values of `y`. I hope to remove the non-convergent results from `res` (or replacing them by non-numerical values) so that these ill-behaving data points do not appear on the plot I generate using `res`. How can I do that?

Comment: Good question! You can wrap each `FindMinimum` with `Check` in order to handle error messages (see the documentation for details.). E.g., `Check[FindMinimum[f[x, #], x], $Failed] & /@ yList` should do what you want.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It works! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome!